# SQL Server : getting multiple min/max values from one query

Tags: sql, sql-server, max, min

I have data similar to the following in SQL Server. I would like to query the single table for the category, min value from `StartDate` and max value from `EndDate`. Hopefully the following mock up of the data will help explain - thanks

DATA:

```
  Category  StartDate   EndDate
  -------------------------------
       A    1/1/2018    1/11/2018
       A    1/3/2018    1/13/2018
       B    1/1/2018    1/11/2018
       B    1/9/2018    1/19/2018
       A    1/5/2018    1/15/2018
       C    1/4/2018    1/14/2018
       A    1/1/2018    1/11/2018
       C    1/7/2018    1/17/2018
```

Desired result of query:

```
  Category  StartDate   EndDate
  --------------------------------
       A    1/1/2018    1/15/2018
       B    1/1/2018    1/19/2018
       C    1/4/2018    1/17/2018
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's wrong with `GROUP BY` and `MIN()` & `MAX()` ?

```
select Category, min(startdate) startdate, max(enddate) enddate
from table t
group by Category;
```

Answer (score 3):

Use group by

```
select category, min(startDate), max(endDate)
from my_table  
group by category
```

Comment: Thanks! I thought it would be more involved.